# Android Package Installer single instance

Tags: android, installation, package, instance, overwrite

I have a private app which is not published via market so I created my own update mechanism from within a service. My problem is if the user presses uninstall, the install new version will appear, and if he presses cancel, he will be taken to a temporary page where he has 1 button that will show the package installer again. However, every time I push the button or the service finds an update, it creates a new instance of the package installer.

Is there a way to make it always have only one instance of the package installer because I get some bugs with multiple instances? Thanks.

Comment: add a little more clarity to this question as it is very hard to find out what is happening exactly... are you trying to uninstall the app from inside the service ... are you trying to update the app from the the app itself,,,, please eloborate.

Comment: When the service receives notification that an update is found,I uninstall an application that the service is not bound to.After this I Install the update by downloading it from a server and installing it.The uninstall/install part is done with the android package installer.But,when you uninstall the current version, you might choose not to install the new one.So you go to a temporary page with a button that restarts the service.But if you push that button over and over(by pressing and then press recent apps)it creates each time a new instance of the android package installer. I want just one.

Comment: cant you just put in a boolean variable that is set once you press the button in the temporary page. and have an if condition to verify that..... Check it... and let me know... other than i think i am not so good with the procedure you have specified. I am learning something new from the question itself.

Comment: This would work but my service is separate from the temporary page.The service also starts the package installer every 3 hours or so.So if the service finds an update,let's say they uninstall but when the install new version appears,they press cancel.That's when my temp page comes in.But from within my page if I press the button it will create a new instance, so I have minimum 2 instances of the package installer in this case scenario.Bool var works for creating single instance in the service OR in my temp app, but they are separate packages and apps, so I can't share variables between them.